# How to publish build status from Jenkins to Bit bucket over SSH for a .net project

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

In Jenkins I was able to fetch project over SSH using GIT and build it successfully.

However not able to find a way to publish the build status from Jenkins to Bit bucket over SSH.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket's build status is an API, which means it's only available over HTTPS.